# What are some Chinese/Asian photo sharing websites similar to Flickr?

Tags: web, flickr, sharing

What are some Chinese/Asian photo sharing websites similar to Flickr?  I want to upload some of my photos to one ow two of these websites with Chinese description and share with Chinese/Asian friends.

Comment: i live in shanghai and it seems most use weibo or google plus.

Comment: Weibo and Google+ are legit analogues to Twitter, not Flickr.

Comment: Google+ is absorbing Picassa and as such is in the same sort of space.

Comment: as i said its what most people use to show off their pics use or don't use up to you . if you are unaware china is not that open to sharing... ANYTHING.

Comment: Can I if there is a reason why you do not want to use flickr? To understand what you are looking for. They support using non-latin characters and when I was recently traveling in Asia I met many fellow photographing backpackers and locals using flickr.

Comment: @Alendri - Flickr's CDN is regularly blocked in China. You can browse the site's UI but the actual photos rarely if ever load. 500px, however, is accessible.

Comment: @Alendri And even when/where it is not blocked (it changes from region to region within China), it is simply *unusably slow*, like many other non-Chinese sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [photos.163.com](http://photo.163.com/) if you can read Chinese, or with aid from Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

Look to see what website in Hong Kong uses.  China seems to block content with its Great Firewall, sometimes at random and changes policies almost daily.

If you can find a photo sharing site in Hong Kong, you most likely will not get blocked and the images would be accessible worldwide.